# The force of gravity is $F_g=+mg$ or $F_g=-mg$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, vectors, conventions

I have noticed that in my classical mechanics course and in the textbook I read for it, seem to ignore the gravitational force's position. For example, if we were dealing with a system with a ball of mass $m$ tied to a ceiling and were asked to find the forces, in an introductory textbook (as least the ones I read) would state the summation of forces as $F_{net}=T−mg$. However, in the mechanics textbook it is written as $F_{net}=T+mg$. I'm wondering why it seems that the downward aspect of the gravitational force is ignored.

Comment: Part of it boils down to some authors preferring $g=-9.81\hat{z}\,{\rm m/s^2}$ while other prefer $g=9.81(-\hat{z})\,{\rm m/s^2}$ where $\hat{z}$ is the unit vector in the $z$-direction.

Comment: $\boldsymbol g$ is being treated as a vector.

Comment: @VladimirVargas, i think you should post this as an (expanded) answer (else i will do it)

Comment: Oscar, how was the $g$ formatted in each book? Was it in bold, or did it have an arrow over it, or something that would indicate it's being treated as a vector? Better yet, can you edit the question to identify the books?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\boldsymbol g$ is a vector. You define it as a scalar only when you have mentioned a clear reference frame in which the sign of $\boldsymbol g$ makes sense.

You could define a vector field from the law of universal gravitation for two bodies $A$ and $B$:

$$\boldsymbol F_{AB}(\boldsymbol r) = -G\frac{m_Am_B}{|\boldsymbol r_{AB}|^2}\boldsymbol {\hat{r}}_{AB}.$$

Comment: maybe add the direction taken in both cases of the examples

Comment: Okay, so in my example, if it is clear that gravity is pointing downward, why would the author refrain from adding the negative sign?

Comment: I have to object to this, on the grounds that in most of the introductory textbooks I've seen, $g$ is used for the _magnitude_ of the gravitational acceleration, not its vector value. I certainly agree that some sources may use $g$ to denote a vector, but the wording of this answer suggests that doing so is a widely accepted convention, which is not the case.

Comment: @DavidZ. $\boldsymbol g$ is a vector. It's used as a magnitude because it is more or less constant

Comment: @VladimirVargas agreed that $\mathbf{g}$ is a vector, but textbooks generally use $g$, which is not.

Comment: They give it a direction depending on the coordinate system they use. An example is when they talk about inclined planes.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not define the direction of the force, you need to do the math explicitly. Usually, a letter like $g$ identifies a scalar quantity. If you want to show a vector, there are a number of typographical conventions. I have seen **$\mathbf{g}$**, $\vec{g}$, $\overline{g}$, $\underline{g}$ ...

So when I have tension up and gravity down, I know that the two are opposing each other, and I need to make that clear in how I describe the math. Vectors are unambiguous - and you will sometimes see them written as $\mathbf{\hat{i},\hat{j},\hat{k}}$ which indicate unit vectors along three orthogonal directions (the $\hat{ }$ symbol describes "unit" something). Then you could write your example as

$$F = T\mathbf{\hat{k}} - m\cdot g\cdot \mathbf{\hat{k}}$$

But it would be just as easy to describe the situation where the tension is at 45 degrees to the vertical:

$$F = T\frac{\mathbf{\hat{i}}+\mathbf{\hat{k}}}{\sqrt{2}} - m\cdot g\cdot \mathbf{\hat{k}}$$

and there is no ambiguity...

It is also possible that your author uses $g=-9.81 m/s^2$ as the convention, in which case you write the sum of the forces in the usual way:

$$F_{total} = \Sigma{F_i} + \Sigma{m_i\cdot a_i}$$

where the direction has to be accounted for by the sign of the accelerations. Again, the usual approach (in anything that isn't a 1D problem) would be to write the whole thing as a vector equation.

Comment: Of course, there's also $g^a$ and $g_a$ for vectors ;)

Comment: @KyleKanos - I can honestly say that I am not familiar with either notation. Maybe I would recognize it in context. Or I am getting old.

Comment: In relativistic mechanics, vectors & covectors are denoted with super and subscripts, respectively. Usually one uses Latin characters for indices 1,2,3 and Greek characters for indices 0,1,2,3.

Comment: Ah - that's where I have seen it.... But aren't those really just _components_ of a vector rather than the entire vector?

Comment: I think it depends on who you ask. Some people use $g^a$ to represent the whole vector, while others demand it to mean a particular component of the index. (Though I typically see it representing the whole of the vector/covector)

Comment: @KyleKanos it would probably be clear from the context in which it is used...